# Why does my navbar shift when I click on it to go to a different page?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, nav

When I click on my navbar to go to a different page on my website, it seems to shift horizontally around a little bit from left to right. Not sure how to fix this issue.

```
    <header>
    <nav id="navbar">
      <h1> William Wang</h1>
      <a href="https://william-wang93.github.io/index.html">Projects</a>
      <a href="https://william-wang93.github.io/html/writings.html">Writings</a>
      <a href="https://william-wang93.github.io/html/about.html">About</a>
    </nav>
    </header>
```

This is the link to my site if that helps [Text] https://stoic-chandrasekhar-4c5ec2.netlify.app/

Answer (score 1):

Only one of your pages has enough content to need a scroll bar. Set `overflow:scroll` to always show the scrollbar.